# cygwin USER and USERNAME are different

Tags: windows-7, cygwin

I changed an account on a Windows 7 machine from 'user' to my own name, and after rebooting, my name is the value of the environment variable `USERNAME`.  But `USER` is still set to 'user'.

How do I change that?  Where does the value of `USER` come from?

```
$ set | egrep "USER=|USERNAME="
USER=user
USERNAME=warren
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Where does the value of USER come from?

Take a look in `/etc/profile`. You will find the following:

```
# Set the user id
USER="$(/usr/bin/id -un)"
```

`id` gets it's data from `/etc/passwd`